# How to add a new color in matplotlib graph (or use colormaps)?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have seen several similar question but none which answers my precise question, so please bear with it before marking it duplicate.

I have to plot n lines on a graph.
The standard value of n is 10 but it can vary. Previously, I used

```
ax.set_color_cycle([plt.cm.Accent(i) for i in np.linspace(0, 1, limit)])
```

Which works well for me.

However, this method has depreciated as of late, and my program gives a warning for the same to use `set_prop_cycle`

I wasn't able to find any example in the documentation http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html that suits my needs of uses a colour bar like accent or hot or cool etc.

**Update**

Sample code for testing:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
limit=10
ax.set_color_cycle([plt.cm.Accent(i) for i in np.linspace(0, 1, limit)])
for limit in range(1,limit+1):
       x=np.random.randint(10, size=10)
       y=limit*x
       plt.plot(x,y,lw=2, label=limit)
       plt.legend(loc='best')
```

What this shows me is:
[image]

The question is how can I use a **colormap** to chose between different shades of a color or the sort? http://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html

Comment: So you just want to split the color bar in `n` equal samples and use those colors for your plot? And can you generate an example that we can run?

Comment: @Chiel I have generated an example for you to run and added an example as well

Comment: You have to define `limit` earlier as you use it in the line before the definition.

Comment: @Chiel Sorry, yes corrected that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a slightly different formulation in order to make use of the more generic `set_prop_cycle`. You have to create a cycler for the argument `'color'` with `plt.cycler` and for the rest do it exactly as you did before:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

limit=10

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_prop_cycle(plt.cycler('color', plt.cm.Accent(np.linspace(0, 1, limit))))
for limit in range(1,limit+1):
    x=np.random.randint(10, size=10)
    y=limit*x
    plt.plot(x,y,lw=2, label=limit)
    plt.legend(loc='best')
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for your answer!

Comment: I don't thing that the loop in `set_prop_cycle` is needed, this: `plt.cm.Accent(np.linspace(0, 1, limit))` gives the same result as `[plt.cm.Accent(i) for i in np.linspace(0, 1, limit)]`

Comment: @Bart You are correct. I did not know this was possible. I have incorporated your comment.